# Scripted commands via ssh on old Centos boxes

Tags: bash, centos, ssh

I need to run the same change on lots of Linux hosts. Before anyone suggests Ansible - that's a non-starter - many of these are Centos 5 which has python 2.4  and current versions of Ansible require a minimum of 2.7.

I've written a wee PHP script which invokes the ssh (with -o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1) locally (via proc_open()) to connect and send commands to the remote system. This works perfectly on the more modern systems. On the Centos 5 boxes, I get an ssh connection and a shell prompt but the first command it sends never gets executed. For the hosts where it works I just needed to append a '\n'. I've tried '\n', '\r\n' and '\n\n' on the Centos boxes to no avail.

The commands work find when I type them in manually on these hosts (and press the "enter" key).

Anyone know why commands are not executing in Centos?

Comment: Can you write a shell script, and then either cat it to ssh (`cat foo.sh | ssh -n some-machine`) or curl it (`ssh some-machine 'curl http://example/foo.sh | bash'`) ? I just tested this on a pi and macOS and both worked fine. You could then loop through your list of hosts and do that. Also check out `pssh`

Comment: When you talk about sending '\n' and '\r', are you talking about newline and carriage return characters, or literal backslashes followed by letters? Also, do you get any feedback (error messages, etc) from the Centos boxes? Do you have anything weird in the shell init scripts (~/.bash_profile, ~/.bashrc, etc) on those boxes? If you send multiple commands, do the commands after the first get executed? What if you delay a couple of seconds between opening the connection and sending the first command?

Comment: @pssh - no. And my code is simply generating a script on the fly

Comment: @GordonDavisson - I mean the relevant control characters. No eedback - my code waits for the PS1 prompt then sends the command. This is echoed back on screen (including the line breaks) but it is not executed. No subsequent prompt is shown.